# How to set focus on a button when react component renders?

Tags: reactjs

I want to set focus on a button as soon as the react component loads, so that the user can just use the keyboard to press the button.

This is what I was trying to do, but this does not seem to work.

```
class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // create a ref to store the textInput DOM element
    this.logButton = React.createRef();

  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
     this.logButton.current.focus();
  }

  render() {
    // tell React that we want to associate the <input> ref
    // with the `textInput` that we created in the constructor
    return (
      <div>
        <Button ref={this.logButton}  outline color="primary" size="sm" onClick={this.logManualRequestModal}>
         Log request
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and I'm using [tabler-react](https://github.com/tabler/tabler-react/) component

Comment: change componentDidUpdate() to componentDidMount() once like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bv2kqe , is that worked ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change componentDidUpdate() to componentDidMount()  like below:

```
componentDidMount(){
     this.logButton.current.focus();
  }
```

and your using Button component from [tabler-react](https://github.com/tabler/tabler-react/blob/master/src/components/Button/Button.react.js) and Button component **ref** defined as **rootRef** check their props for ref in Button Component.

So change ref like this :

```
<Button rootRef={this.logButton} color="primary">A Button</Button>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bv2kqe) and  [ref](https://github.com/tabler/tabler-react/blob/master/src/components/Button/Button.react.js)

Comment: I've already tried this, but this also does not work. 
the current object is always null. 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null

this is the error which I am getting.

Comment: <Button> is a third party component ?

Comment: I am using https://github.com/tabler/tabler-react 
So yes <Button> is a third party component

Answer (score 0):

1. `button` is HTML built-in tag. you should change `Button` to `button` (lowercase)
2. change `componentDidUpdate` to `componentDidMount`.